# Is there a way to import Blogger into bbPress?

Tags: import, bbpress, blogger

I have a blog on Blogger that I would like to turn into a bbPress forum. This is a blog that has essentially been used as a forum, so bbPress is a better solution. Unfortunately, by default bbPress only seems to be able to import from phpBB and bbPress. I imported Blogger into WordPress as posts thinking I might be able to convert the posts to topics, with comments being the replies, but I can't seem to do that either. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.  And unfortunately that's because you've been using Blogger to do something it was never intended to do.

I'm not saying this is a bad thing.

Blogger (and WordPress) are built to handle an article format:

- One author publishes a large article
- Other writers create short-format comments
- Comments and replies are threaded together for context.

bbPress (and phpBB) are built to handle a discussion format:

- One author creates a topic (usually short-format)
- Other writers contribute responses to that topic
- Aside from the separation of individual topics, there is no other contextual threading

Each tool is meant to be used in a different environment.  Unfortunately, that also means there are very few (you're the second I've ever heard of) use cases of migrating from one to the other.

TLDR - there is no automated tool.  Your safest bet is to do a manual migration (which will be time-consuming, I know).  Your second best bet would be to hire a dev to script the migration for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realize we've been using Blogger to do something it was never intended to do. This exactly why we want to move away from it. I wrote my own import script this afternoon which seems to be working well, just thought I'd save myself some time if there was already a tool out there. Perhaps I will release my script as a plugin at some point.

Comment: If anyone else is interested in this, [here is the script](https://github.com/nosecreek/Posts-to-bbPress) that I used in plugin form. May move it to wordpress.org at some point, but it is pretty rough right now.

https://github.com/nosecreek/Posts-to-bbPress